# How do I handle multiple EVT_TEXT events in wxPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

This is one part of a two part question (other part is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479478/how-do-i-edit-the-color-of-a-word-without-generating-evt-text-in-wxpython))

So here's what I'm looking for: A function which is bound to the `EVT_TEXT` event of a text control that waits a few seconds, then calls another function at the end of the delay time.  Thats easy enough, but, I'd like it to reset the delay time every time a new `EVT_TEXT` event is generated.  The effect I'm looking for is to have a user type into the text control, then after I assume they're done, I run the function described in the other part of this question which spell checks what they've written.

So the simple approach I tried was this:

```
def OnEdit(self, event):
    for i in range(0,3):
        print i
        time.sleep(1)
```

However, this just forces a 3 second wait, no matter what.  How do I "break in" to this function to reset the counter?  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Turns out the way to do this was with threading.  Yippee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full threading answer, built with the help of [this](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) tutorial:

```
from threading import *
import wx
import time

EVT_RESULT_ID = wx.NewId()

def EVT_RESULT(win, func):
    win.Connect(-1, -1, EVT_RESULT_ID, func)

class MyGui(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.spellchkthrd = None
        #lots of stuff

        self.input = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, "", size=(200, 150), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_LEFT|wx.TE_RICH)        
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnEdit, self.input)
        EVT_RESULT(self, self.OnSplCheck)    

    def OnEdit(self, event):
        if not self.spellchkthrd:
            self.spellchkthrd = SpellCheckThread(self)  
        else:
            self.spellchkthrd.newSig()

    def OnSplCheck(self, event):
        self.spellchkthrd = None
        #All the spell checking stuff

class ResultEvent(wx.PyEvent):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.PyEvent.__init__(self)
        self.SetEventType(EVT_RESULT_ID)

class SpellCheckThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, panel):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.count = 0
        self.panel = panel
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while self.count < 1.0:
            print self.count
            time.sleep(0.1)            
            self.count += 0.1

        wx.PostEvent(self.panel, ResultEvent())

    def newSig(self):
        print "new"
        self.count = 0
```