# How do I edit the color of a word without generating EVT_TEXT in wxPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

This is one part of a two part question (other part is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479459/how-do-i-handle-multiple-evt-text-events-in-wxpython))

So I'm working with wxPython and PyEnchant trying to get some fancy features going.  Specifically, I want my text controls to change the color of mispelled words.  I can do this if I bind the following code to a button. (where `input` is a `wx.TextCtrl`)

```
 chkr = SpellChecker("en_US",self.input.GetValue())
 words = self.input.GetValue().split()
 wrongWords = [err.word for err in chkr]
 self.input.ChangeValue("")
 for word in words:
     if not word in wrongWords:
         self.input.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.BLACK))
         self.input.AppendText(word+" ")
     else:
         self.input.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.RED)) 
         self.input.AppendText(word+" ")
```

This works exactly how I want it, except that I do not want to have to bind it to a button.

This is where the second question comes in.  I want it to happen automatically after the user has finished editing.  You can see the other question for a full discussion of whhat that means, but in the scope of this question, all it means is that I must do the above operation without generating an `EVT_TEXT` event.

`ChangeValue()` is identical to `SetValue()`, but it does not generate `EVT_TEXT`, so is there an analogous function to `AppendText()` which does same?  Or failing that, is there a way to suppress `EVT_TEXT` when it is generated by `AppendText()` or someway to determine if the event came from `AppendText()`?  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I've managed to get a work around going by using `Unbind()`, but I'm still open to a better method if anyone can find one

Comment: I was just going to recommend `Unbind`, so I think it is just the most obvious way. Also for `PyEnchant` use, I have a good experience with using it together with `wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl`. You can do cool stuff like underline in red etc. I have Firefox-like spell-checking with even recommended correction right-click menu going on.

Comment: Interesting.  That sounds pretty ideal, but unfortunately I think it would be too much of a pain to implement (we're at about 6,500 lines).   But the next time I start a project, I'll definitely use them!

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit of pain to connect and hack together, especially if you have to mess with unicode. Unfortunately, I do not have it done as complete widget. Next time I start a project I will do that :-). But anyways, if you decide to try it in a future, I can send you a messy sample to work with - just PM me.