# How do I pass highlighted text from text control in wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm working on building some extra functions based off the PyEnchant spell checker for my wxPython GUI.  Currently, I have my text controls turn misspelled words red (detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479459/how-do-i-handle-multiple-evt-text-events-in-wxpython) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479478/how-do-i-edit-the-color-of-a-word-without-generating-evt-text-in-wxpython)), but I'd like to incorporate the suggestions feature of PyEnchant.

Ideally, I'd like to have the suggestions pop up when the user right clicks on the highlighted word in the text control similar to how Microsoft Word does it.  But this sounds pretty hard, so I'd settle for just throwing up a `wx.SingleChoiceDialog` when the user highlights the word then presses "alt+s" (using an accelerator table).

The key is being able to pull the text the user highlights.  I can figure out everything else, but this continues to elude me to the point where I'm beginning to doubt if its 
possible.  Hopefully it is and *you* know how to do it, thanks in advance

Comment: Haven't tried it, but `GetStringSelection` (or `GetSelection` for the actual offsets) should get the text for you... does that work?

Comment: I haven't seen those in the docs, I'll play around with it

Comment: Works like a dream, if you write an answer for it I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, the `GetStringSelection` function will return the current text selection.

The documentation for `wxEditText` doesn't show this function, but `wxTextCtrl` is also derived from `wxTextEntry`, and that's where the function is defined.